# How to play a sound file under Android browser

Tags: android, browser, audio, playback

Is there any way to play a sound file under Android browser?

Comment: assuming that user has a flash player and it is always enabled (which is rare) you can create a small swf file to play some audio. as far as I remember m.gmail.com uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, based on this:
http://textopiablog.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/browser-support-for-html5-audio/

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the emulator in the android 2.3 SDK, HTML5 audio works fine (all common formats) in android 2.3. But unless all your users have Nexus S phones, that doesn't help you much at the moment. :/

Comment: Oh, actually another user posted a workaround that is supposed to work in 1.6+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069124/playing-html5-audio-in-android-browser/4480795#4480795