# HTML5 audio player for mobile with "Plugins on demand" setting active

Tags: android, ios, flash, html5-audio

I've been trying to find a working HTML5 audio player script that works on mobile phones (particularly on Android and iOS). If it were just about Android, I'd be using a Flash player - but I need a solution that works on both platforms.

The problem with all the players I've tried so far is the setting "Load Plugins on demand" on Android phones (stock browser and Dolphin). If that setting is active (I believe it is by default), the HTML5 player will show instead of the Flash fallback. But neither the stock browser nor Dolphin are able to play the audio file as HTML5, for some reason.

And because plugins are disabled by default, the Flash fallback is not visible and can't be activated as usual. So in essence, Android devices that have the "on demand" setting enabled can't play the audio file at all.

Is there any player that actually works right off the bat when this setting is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I get audio just fine from [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) on my iphone and my android nexus one. It doesn't fallback to flash though, like [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/) does.

Comment: Do you get an error of any kind? I just tried it on both my phones and got sound.

Comment: No, sorry... it just doesn't play any sound at all, neither in stock nor in Dolphin. Drag&drop doesn't work either. I've reverted to uploading the mp3s to Youtube for now, by the way - their iframe seems to be the only one that works both on Android and on iOS. I appreciate the help though :)

Comment: what version of android? what model of phone?

Comment: Moto Atrix MB860, currently on Android 2.2.2 stock. Are you the Buzz dev? If so, love the design :)

Comment: No, I'm not the dev. I'm working on a mobile app that involves web audio playback, so I'm interested in where Buzz works and where it doesn't. So I checked my wife's android phone which is running 2.2, and it doesn't work, but mine is 2.3.3 and it does. So I wonder if html5 audio works at all on android 2.2

Comment: apparently you can use the video tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069124/playing-html5-audio-in-android-browser