# Dynamic HTML audio not loading/playing in Android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, audio

I am trying to load audios dynamically in my project. I've used jPlayer, MediaElement.js and javascript create audio element. Everything is working fine in desktop browser but fails in android(OS 4.1+) browsers except firefox. I've attached the codes of various player that I tried.

jPlayer:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({                

    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "sample.mp3",
            oga: "sample.ogg"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    wmode: "window",
    smoothPlayBar: true,    
    keyEnabled: true,
    ended : function(){
        //$(this).jPlayer("stop" );
        //$(this).jPlayer("playHead",100);
       if(pCnt != tocArr.length-1){
        $("#nextIns").css("display","block");
       }
    }

  });
```

MediaElement.js:

```
audioPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer("#player", {
pauseOtherPlayers: false,
success: function (mediaElement) {  
    var sources = [{ src: "sample.mp3" }];              
mediaElement.setSrc("sample.mp3"); 
mediaElement.pause();
mediaElement.load();
//mediaElement.play();
}   
});
```

javascript:

I have added audio tag in html page and added the below code in my JS

JS:

```
audioElement = document.getElementById('player');
audioElement.pause();
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sample.mp3');
audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please guide me on this.

Comment: did you allow using js for webview? like `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: and inserting an <audio> tag directly in html? see http://pc-shooter.ch/ on my htc oneV (Android 4.0.3) with the internal browser it plays. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069124/playing-html5-audio-in-android-browser?rq=1

Comment: Yes I've added audio tag in html page and tried to update the src in js.