# Android browser html5 Audio won't play

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm making a web app that plays a small mp3 file to notify the user for an update. I am using the HTML5 Audio API:

```
var notifyAudio = new Audio("path/to/audio.mp3");
//some code...
//Callback function called when I want to notify the user
function notify(){
  notifyAudio.play()
}
```

It works perfectly in the Chrome desktop browser, but when I tested it in the Android devices, It won't, not even loading the mp3 file, her is what I get in the Chrome Device debugger

[image]

Comment: Take a look [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10546)...  But maybe this can help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4480795/4385913)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to prefix the path in Android for Media playing with /android_asset/www. See my blog post for a full demo here - http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/06/23/Cordova-Media-API-Example. Also, make sure you actually added the Media plugin.

Comment: Hi Raymond
It's not a cordova/phonegap app, It's a full web app using the device browser.

Comment: You showed the Network panel in the screen shot - is anything in the console?