# playing audio on mobile browser throgh html audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio

how can we play audio on mobile broswer is playing on desktop browser  but not playing on mobile what is the solution for the particular problem.. 
code is
var audio=new Audio('sound.mp4')
audio.play()

Comment: You need to review the accepted codec in your device and according to this call the respective file. Look at [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) to see the accepted codecs in android and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069124/playing-html5-audio-in-android-browser) there are some possible workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari, and probably others, only allow audio to play in response to a user action. So `element.addEventListener( 'click', () => audio.play() )`  will work, but the `autoplay` attribute or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => audio.play() )` won't.

Comment: jQuery(function(){
          ///  audio.play();
     
            jQuery('#playFancy').click();

        });
         document.getElementById('playFancy').addEventListener( 'click', () => audio.play() ) that is my code but its still not working on mobile browser

Comment: There you go. It has to be a real user action.

Comment: i cant have a real action i am generating a click event of a button through jquery and want audio to play through that event

Comment: Sorry but the browser won't let you do that.